# How to derive the put-call parity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, finance

The following solution seems quite vague to me as I am not too sure how they thought of putting the terms on the right hand side together and similarly for lhs. I know that max(..) is the payoff, but why are we adding the strike to it?

Any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Being long a call and short a put at the same strike (and same expiry)  means that you are guaranteed to purchase the stock at the strike price on the expiry date (assuming rational exercise).  That's the same as a forward trade at the strike price.

Comment: Your solution is fine, except the portfolio with 1 put has 1 share of stock, not $S_0$ shares of stock.

Comment: why would the $Ke^{-rT}$ dollars become K at time T?

Comment: Because you can invest them at the risk free rate.